# Pulling Private GoLang Packages from Google Cloud Artifact Registry when Building Cloud Functions (Gen 2)

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-artifact-registry

Long time listener, glad to be here today.

I have a golang module that rests in Google Cloud Artifact Registry

[image]

I have a cloud function that utilizes this package

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "html"
    "net/http"

    "example.com/boomer"
    "github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-go/functions"
)

func helloHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, boomer.Bang())
    var d struct {
        Name string `json:"name"`
    }
    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&d); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello, World!")
        return
    }
    if d.Name == "" {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello, World!")
        return
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %s!", html.EscapeString(d.Name))
}

func main() {
    functions.HTTP("HelloHTTP", helloHTTP)
}

// helloHTTP is an HTTP Cloud Function with a request parameter.
```

My problem is that no matter how I go about deploying this cloud function, I can't get it to pull the Artifact Registry private image in during the build process. My Cloudbuild YAML is:

```
steps:
  - name: golang
    entrypoint: go
    args: [ 'run', 'github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/artifact-registry-go-tools/cmd/auth@v0.1.0', 'add-locations', '--locations=${_LOCATION}' ]
    env:
      # Set GOPROXY to the public proxy to pull the credential helper tool
      - 'GOPROXY=proxy.golang.org'

  - name: golang
    entrypoint: go
    args: [ 'run', 'github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/artifact-registry-go-tools/cmd/auth@v0.1.0', 'refresh' ]
    env:
      - 'GOPROXY=proxy.golang.org'
      - 'GONOPROXY=github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/artifact-registry-go-tools'



  - name: golang
    entrypoint: go
    args: [ 'run', '.' ]
    env:
      - 'GONOPROXY=github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/artifact-registry-go-tools'
      - 'GONOSUMDB=*.${_MODULE_PATH}'
      - 'GOPRIVATE=*.${_MODULE_PATH}'

# Deploy

  - name: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk
    args:
      - gcloud
      - functions
      - deploy
      - hello-go
      - --allow-unauthenticated
      - --region=us-central1
      - --source=.
      - --trigger-http
      - --runtime=go121
      - --entry-point=HelloHTTP
      - --set-build-env-vars=^;^GONOSUMDB="${_MODULE_PATH}";GOPRIVATE="${_MODULE_PATH}";GONOPROXY="github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/artifact-registry-go-tools";GOPROXY="${_LOCATION}-go.pkg.dev/${_PROJECT_ID}/${_REPOSITORY},https://proxy.golang.org,direct"

options:
  env:    # Disable GO sumdb checks for private modules.
    - 'GONOPROXY=github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/artifact-registry-go-tools'
    - 'GOPROXY=${_LOCATION}-go.pkg.dev/${_PROJECT_ID}/${_REPOSITORY},https://proxy.golang.org,direct'
    - 'GONOSUMDB=${_MODULE_PATH}'
    - 'GOPRIVATE=${_MODULE_PATH}'
```

All the steps are fine in the build process, except for the final deployment step where it should be deploying to Cloud Functions. I keep getting the same error, which I would expect if it was trying to directly proxy to example.com/boomer. I've adjusted the Proxy to come from my private registry first.

The meaningful part of the error in the cloud build logs that are output when step 3 of the above kickas off the Cloud Build Process:

```
severity: "INFO"
textPayload: "Step #2 - "build":    github.com/pkg/errors: example.com/boomer@v0.0.16: unrecognized import path "example.com/boomer": reading https://example.com/boomer?go-get=1: 404 Not Found"
timestamp: "2023-12-15T22:00:53.973146065Z"
```

Not sure what I need to adjust here, any sights would be helpful.

I was expecting the function to successfully deploy, however I don't think the Cloud Build login and deployment of the github artifact registry tool carry over to the build process kicked off by the cloud-sdk running the deploy gcloud CLI command.

Possibly private build pools? But that seems like a little much.

Comment: 1) Does your project build locally? If not, then solve that first. 2) Include the contents of `go.mod` in your post. 3) My guess is that you have not configured the Artifact Registry path for your example module based on the error message. https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/go/manage-modules

Comment: The project does run locally. The problem is the finally step in the cloudbuild.yaml - during the Cloud Function deploy request, a separate cloudbuild action is started (this is the default for deploying second gen CF's). That second cloudbuild action doesn't have the login to the private repo and since its kicked off by the buildpack associated with the gcloud functions deploy command, I don't have the ability to init it by refreshing the auth token and the cloud-build golang git tools (see the first step in the CloudBuild process)